# how does laravel know if it's on https or http?

Tags: laravel, https

how does laravel know if it's on https or http?

I just installed https on my app but I have customer who enabled cloudfare https on his website and links that my app generates are http and not https despite that the address in the browser is https?

How does laravel know? Does server tell it that it's on https or does it figure this out it self?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if visitor connected over SSL on CloudFlare Pro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845903/determine-if-visitor-connected-over-ssl-on-cloudflare-pro)

Comment: Short summary of the above: You need to configure your webserver to handle the `X-Forwarded-Proto` call, or you can turn on HTTPS between Cloudflare and your server. Right now, while users connect to Cloudflare via HTTPS, Cloudflare is connecting to your server as HTTP. See https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean- - if you can, go from "Flexible" SSL to "Strict" SSL.